# Can a Facebook group be divided into different sections?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

I have created a university based group on Facebook which enables me and my colleagues to help each other in university.

To make the group efficient and easy to use (by me and my colleagues) I want to divide the group into sections which represent the different university subjects (like mathematics, chemistry, physics etc.) and to make posts and upload pictures, videos and documents (Word, Excel, PowerPoint, OneNote & Access) for every section (or in my case for every university subject separately).

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

No, sorry, this is not possible. There is no current way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

No, the only way to do this is to have separate groups.

Answer (score 0):

**However, there is a similar way you can do this. Try Google+, it actually has a *great* way to do groups--where every post is categorized into sections.** I believe there might also be Google Drive implementation for uploading attachments and what not, but I'm not as confident for that aspect. In the least you could upload it to Google Drive then give them the sharable link of course

Answer (score -3):

They do have this feature. I'm unsure how other group admins are using it, but I see that they are.

Comment: Hi kat, it's helpful to provide some evidence, especially when your answer contradicts the other (albeit much earlier) ones.  Could you add a reference or an example, please?